# Adjusting Thickness of Text Overline

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an element with the following CSS properties:

```
text-decoration: overline;
text-decoration-color: blue;
```

The problem is the overline is very small and not very thick at all. I would like to increase the thickness of this overline.

I have done some research and it looks like there is no CSS property to increase the thickness of the overline.

I have read certain things about adding a top border but that top border doesn't sit right above the text and it moves the entire element down on the page.

Since I'm doing this within a bootstrap nav bar the element moving down is a pretty big problem.

Any ideas on how to make the overline more visible and increase the thickness of the line?

Below is the full snippet of code including the HTML I'm using.

```css
.active {
  text-decoration: overline;
  text-decoration-color: #DF3E38;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">My Site</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Sign Up</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Login</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method is to include the top border at all times, with a transparent color. This factors in the width, which  stabilizes the element when interacting with a pseudo-class, such as `:active` or `:hover`.

Then just change the color on `:active`, `:hover`, etc. Here's an example:

```css
div {
    border-top: 3px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
}

div:hover {
    border-top-color: blue;
}

/* non-essential decorative styles */

nav {
    display: flex;
}
div {
    width: 100px;
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: lightgreen;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <div>nav item</div>
    <div>nav item</div>
    <div>nav item</div>
    <div>nav item</div>
</nav>
```

---

**EDIT**

From the comments:

> Ok now if the height of the element is greater that border will always
>   rest at the top of the div container. Is there anyway to make it rest
>   right about the text itself instead of at the top of the div
>   container? More similar to how `text-decoration: overline;` works or
>   not?

```css
span {
    border-top: 3px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
}

span:hover {
    border-top-color: blue;
}

div:nth-child(1) > span { line-height: 1; }
div:nth-child(2) > span { line-height: .7; }
div:nth-child(3) > span { line-height: .5; }
div:nth-child(4) > span { line-height: 1.5; }

/* non-essential decorative styles */

nav {
    display: flex;
}
div {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: lightgreen;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <div><span>nav item</span></div>
    <div><span>nav item</span></div>
    <div><span>nav item</span></div>
    <div><span>nav item</span></div>
</nav>
```

### [**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ybfjx03r/3/)

Comment: Ok now if the height of the element is greater that border will always rest at the top of the div container. Is there anyway to make it rest right about the text itself instead of at the top of the div container? More similar to how `text-decoration: overline;` works or not?

Comment: Forgot to mention this a few days ago. But this solution is actually great because inside of the `a` tag wrapping the text in a `span` and adding a border to that works really well. Would be awesome if the code snippets related directly to the code I provided, but was easy to adjust to fit my needs. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `:after` pseudo element to create line instead of `text-decoration` and set `position: absolute` to position `:after` element.

```css
a.active {
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 1px 0;
}
a.active:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 5px;
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a class="active" href="#">Sign Up</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Other option is to use `display: inline-flex` on parent element with `flex-direction: column` and `:before` pseudo-element.

```css
a.active {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  line-height: 0.8;
}
a.active:before {
  content: '';
  height: 5px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a class="active" href="#">Sign Up</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Although this works it creates it at the very top of the element. Is there anyway to have that line rest right above the text similar to how the `text-decoration: overline;` works? If that doesn't make sense I can show an image of what I'm talking about.

Comment: Well one option would be to adjust padding and height, https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1123/

Answer (score 3):

You cannot adjust text-decoration thickness.

You can however simulate an overline similar to text-decoration but where you can change the width by using...

1. `border-top` and the right ammount of `padding-top`. Here you can specify the `border-top-width` as desired.
2. `::before` pseudoelement, you can specify the `height` to be as big or small as needed.

```css
a{
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 1rem 0;
}

a.overline-default{
  text-decoration: overline;
}

a.overline-border{
  border-top: 2px solid;
  padding-top: 0;
  line-height: 1; /* you may need to play with this too */
}

a.overline-before::before{
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 2px; /* you can play with this one for the distance */
  height: 2px;
  background: blue;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<a href="#0" class="overline-default">overline default</a>
<a href="#0" class="overline-border">overline with border</a>
<a href="#0" class="overline-before">overline with ::before</a>
```

Comment: Looks like your code sample is an underline. I'm looking for an overline.

Comment: Yeah I apologize for that. I've just edited it, sorry.